# Duration between two dates ignoring weekends

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using the *Days Between* calculation to return the number of days between two given dates `(EndDate-StartDate).Days`.

Is it possible to perform this calculation whilst discounting weekend days (Sat & Sun) in the same way that the `NETWORKDAYS` command functions in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This can be done but the calculation is a bit complicated. This calculation will check the number of days between the two dates to get a number of weeks. It will then check to see if there are any partial days that need to be added. Then it will remove weekends based on the number of weeks, and where the partial days start in relation to Sunday.

The full calculation will provide you with the number of business days between two dates.

```
=(((EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1) % 7) - Math.Max(Math.Min((((EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1) % 7) - (if EndDate.DayOfWeek = "Monday" then 1 else if EndDate.DayOfWeek = "Tuesday" then 2 else if EndDate.DayOfWeek = "Wednesday" then 3 else if EndDate.DayOfWeek = "Thursday" then 4 else 5), 2), 0) + (Math.Floor(((EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1) / 7)) * 5
```